# using javascript to change background color

Tags: javascript, css, background-color

```
function schrijvenles1(){
var text = document.getElementById("schrijven-les1").value;
var imageElement = document.getElementById("goed-fout");

//het antwoord is correct
if (text === "Hoe heet je" || text ===  "hoe heet je" || text === "Hoe heet je?" || text === "hoe heet je?") {
    imageElement.src = "goed.png";
    imageElement.src = true;
}
// het antwoord is iets anders
else {
    imageElement.src = "fout.png";  
    imageElement.src = false;
}


if(imageElement.src = true) {

     document.getElementById("voortgang-button").style.backGroundcolor = '#99c262' ;
}

if(imageElement.src = false) {

    document.getElementById("voortgang-button").style.backGroundcolor = "#ff6c60"
}
```

This is my java text, this seems a bit out of the blue, but I want to change the background color from a button, depending whether the answer is correct or if it's wrong

the css which belongs to "voortgang-button" =

```
button#controle-luisteren1 {
   width:55px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 20px;
   margin-left:150px;
```

}

however; now is the question what am I doing wrong? I am a beginning JavaScript programmer, and dutch, so please bear with me ;).

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: "text=="  instead of "text===" , "imageElement.src === true" instead of  "imageElement.src = true"

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you want but im pretty sure you have a mistake in the comparation, you should use '==' instead of '=' when comparing.

```
if(imageElement.src == true) {

     document.getElementById("voortgang-button").style.backGroundcolor = '#99c262' ;
}

if(imageElement.src == false) {

    document.getElementById("voortgang-button").style.backGroundcolor = "#ff6c60"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you're not closing the `schrijvenles1()` function. Add an extra `}` at the end.

Second, you are using `backGroundcolor` wrong, it should look like this:

`document.getElementById("voortgang-button").style.backgroundColor`

Also the comparison operator is wrong `=` should be `==` or `===`. You're now just saying it's `true` or `false`. You are not actually checking if it is.

```
if(imageElement.src === true) {

     document.getElementById("voortgang-button").style.backgroundColor = '#99c262' ;
}

if(imageElement.src === false) {

    document.getElementById("voortgang-button").style.backgroundColor = "#ff6c60"
}
```

Another thing wrong with you code is value assignment. You first add a string value to the `imageElement.src` and then immediately replace it with a `boolean` which doesn't make sense in your case.

And another thing, in your javascript code you have a button with id `controle-luisteren1` and in css a button with id `controle-luisteren1` which is confusing.

Comment: i was using the same id's because i want the java to change the backgroundColor in the Css, or is this not possible at all? and what do you mean by replacing it with a boolean (you are speaking with a relativly new java user here;) )

Comment: First of all, as someone already said in a comment, `java` is not `javascript`. Booleans are `true`, `false` for example.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry for misunderstanding the difference between java and javascript. However, how should I solve this? just: true==="#99c262"; ?

Comment: No. That's wrong. `true==="#99c262";` again, doesn't make sense. The key two resolve your problem is reading carrefully the answers. Based on that you can make a working code.

Comment: @dickdoeven, would help understand better what you are doing if you update your question with the `HTML` too.

Answer (score 0):

This following way is not right

```
imageElement.src = "goed.png";
imageElement.src = true;
```

Here first you are assigning a value and then again overwriting with a new value. So `src` will not have the image. Instead of modifying the `src` attribute use [**data**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute

Secondly if you want to add the background color using js

```
yourElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Note the casing

Thirdly this is also not right.

```
if(imageElement.src = true)
```

Here you are just assigning true or false but there is no condition. It should be like this

```
if(imageElement.src === true){
//rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function schrijvenles1(){
    var text = document.getElementById("schrijven-les1").value;
    var imageElement = document.getElementById("goed-fout");

    //het antwoord is correct
    if (text === "Hoe heet je" || text ===  "hoe heet je" || text === "Hoe heet je?" || text === "hoe heet je?") {
        imageElement.src = "goed.png";
        imageElement.src = true;
    }
    // het antwoord is iets anders
    else {
        imageElement.src = "fout.png";  
        imageElement.src = false;
    }


    if(imageElement.src = true) {

         document.getElementById("voortgang-button").style.backgroundColor  = '#99c262' ;
    }

    if(imageElement.src = false) {

        document.getElementById("voortgang-button").style.backgroundColor  = "#ff6c60"
    }
}   
</script>
<style>
#controle-luisteren1 {
   width:55px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 20px;
   margin-left:150px;
}
#voortgang-button{width:100;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="schrijven-les1" value="">
    <img src="" id="goed-fout">
    <button id="voortgang-button" >voortgang-button </button>
    <button id="test" onclick="schrijvenles1()" value="click"> clcik</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shoudl add an explanation to your code when you're answering a question. Also, your code is full of mistakes.